How to avoid Artefacts Using Boolean Modifier on Ocean
I am animating a Rowing Boat using the technique described in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2G1liNkhcw
In order for the boat to be floating in the ocean, boolean modifier has to be set and the boat copied and turned into a convex hull. This is hidden in renders but you use it to cut a hole in the ocean. However it leads to artefacts that renders the render unusable.
I have tried different bool methods, and the exact works best but still really bad. I need to find a solution to this. All I can think of at this stage is to some how render the boat separately without the ocean and overlay it. But that would be a bit awkward and fiddly.
I've tried adding a subsurface modifier (in between ocean and boolean), but maybe I am not cranking it up high enough? I've also tried reducing the size of the ocean but that hasn't worked. I guess cranking up the resolution of the sub surf might help, but that would likely increase render time.
Any advice gratefully appreciated.


I'm not sure I can tell what artecfacts you're referring to. Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Thanks for your response. No it's not really practical to share - it's too large. The top picture shows only slight artefacts, the bottom picture shows it severely. The result is flickering between them. Right now I am trying cranking up the subsurf modifier to 4 and changing the solver for the boolean to "fast". Unfortunately it does look like it will impact render time.

NB....the renders flicker between the top and bottom pics. I might be able to link a short bit of video - that might show it better.

Adding more subdivs to before the boolean mod is not going to help so def stop doing that.

I hear you loud and clear. Have just stopped it. You are quite right it did not work.

So it seems the only solution is to create a layer for the boat (and hold out the oars) and composite them separately. The boolean trick is just a mess.

Yeah, that was also my first instinct as well. Fix it in the composite.
